# Converting date persian Datepicker to Gregorian using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to convert persian Datepicker, indicated with 1 in text box, to Gregorian date, and copy it to a second text box.

I have tried:

```
$('#textbox1').persianDatepicker({
     format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    observer: true,
    var e=$('#textbox1').val();
    var gregDate = gregoriantojd(e);
        $('#textbox2').val(gregDate);

});
```

But this does not work.

How can I make this code work?

Comment: Please tell me how to write the following code:

Comment: I want the quantity indicated in textbox 1 that I receive via Persian datapicker, to be converted to Gregorian date and put in textbox 2.

Comment: `gregoriantojd()` looks like a PHP function. There is no built-in Javascript or jquery function with that name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a way to convert from a persian calender to a gregorian date. I tried to build an example, please have a look.

At the bottom I added the javascript from the [official documentation](https://behzadi.github.io/persianDatepicker/#convertDates).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').persianDatepicker({
    onShow: function() {
      $('#converted').text('');
    },
    onSelect: function () {
      var pd = new persianDate();
      var value = pd.parse($("#datepicker").val());
      var jdf = new jDateFunctions();
      $('#converted').text(jdf.getGDate(value));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker/master/css/persianDatepicker-default.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker/master/js/persianDatepicker.min.js"></script>

<h2> - Convert Jalali(shamsi) date to Gregorian(miladi) date</h2>
<input type="text" placeholder="Click to select date" id="datepicker" />
<div id="converted"></div>
```

From the [official website of jQuery Persian Datepicker](https://behzadi.github.io/persianDatepicker/#convertDates) (assuming that you really use that plugin):

```
$("#year, #month, #day").on("change", function () {
    $("#month").val() > 6 ? $("#day-31").hide() : $("#day-31").show();;
    showConverted();
});
$("#year").keyup(showConverted);
function showConverted() {
    try{
        var pd = new persianDate();
        pd.year = parseInt($("#year").val());
        pd.month = parseInt($("#month").val());
        pd.date = parseInt($("#day").val());

        var jdf = new jDateFunctions();
        $("#converted").html("Gregorian :  " + jdf.getGDate(pd)._toString("YYYY/MM/DD") + "     [" + jdf.getGDate(pd) + "]Julian:  " + jdf.getJulianDayFromPersian(pd));
    } catch (e) {
        $("#converted").html("Enter the year correctly!");
    }
}
```